# Oracle Spatial. Get the Projected coordinates [local SRID] and Geographic coordinates [WGS84] from an area centroid

Tags: sql, oracle, gis

Newbie here - excuse me for any misdemeanor

I’ve done a sql script to get the Projected coordinates (**M** and **P**) as well as the Geographic Coordinates (**LONG** and **LAT**) from a (area) centroid from table **AETA**, as well as another attribute (**CONCELHO**), from the view **VAETA**.

The base geometry is in table (AETA). This table is comprised of 2 attributes [IPID, GEOMETRY] and contains area type geometries.
The view (VAETA) is related to table AETA – they share the IPID attribute.

Here’s the script:

```
SELECT A.ipid, (SDO_GEOM.SDO_CENTROID(SDO_GEOM.SDO_ARC_DENSIFY(A.GEOMETRY, m.diminfo, 'arc_tolerance=0.05'),1).sdo_point.x) as M, SDO_GEOM.SDO_CENTROID(SDO_GEOM.SDO_ARC_DENSIFY(A.GEOMETRY, m.diminfo, 'arc_tolerance=0.05'),1).sdo_point.y) as P, A.CONCELHO, TRANSFORM_LONG_LAT_PT((SDO_GEOM.SDO_CENTROID(SDO_GEOM.SDO_ARC_DENSIFY(A.GEOMETRY, m.diminfo, 'arc_tolerance=0.05'),1).sdo_point.x), SDO_GEOM.SDO_CENTROID(SDO_GEOM.SDO_ARC_DENSIFY(A.GEOMETRY, m.diminfo, 'arc_tolerance=0.05'),1).sdo_point.y)) AS T FROM VAETA A, user_sdo_geom_metadata m WHERE m.table_name = 'AETA' AND m.column_name = 'GEOMETRY';
```

Here’s the results I get from my sql script:

**IPID || M || P || CONCELHO || T**

50040615 || 58243.8292298382 || -95032.5884906886 || Borba || MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,4326,MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(-7.46254163019826,38.8103393988376,NULL),NULL,NULL)

50041533 || 46178.4608566094 || -125300.367916971 || Redondo || MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,4326,MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(-7.6034580874097,38.5384058748327,NULL),NULL,NULL)

…   …   …   …   …

My problem is to get Longitude and Latitude from the geometry object (column T), So that I would get a table like this:

**IPID || M || P || CONCELHO || LONG || LAT**

50040615 || 58243.8292298382 || -95032.5884906886 || Borba || -7.46254163019826 || 38.8103393988376

50041533 || 46178.4608566094 || -125300.367916971 || Redondo || -7.6034580874097 || 38.5384058748327

…   …   …   …       …

Anyone knows how to do this **in one go, in the same sql script**?

I’m a bit lost with the syntax specifics of it all...
I've tried several times and I keep on getting errors that I can't really fix.

Thanks in advance,

Best regards,
Pedro

Note: I’m using **a function (transform_long_lat_pt)** that converts coordinates from SRID 3763 [ETRS89 / Portugal TM06] to 4326 [WGS 84]. I’ve tried the function and the results are ok.

**The M and P Projected coordinates are in SRID 3763 [ETRS89 / Portugal TM06]**

**The LONG and LAT Geographic coordinates should be in SRID 4326 [WGS 84]**

```
Funtion transform_long_lat_pt

create or replace function transform_long_lat_pt(longitude in number, 
                                           latitude in number)
return SDO_GEOMETRY deterministic is
begin
     return sdo_cs.transform(sdo_geometry(2001, 3763, 
                sdo_point_type(longitude, latitude, NULL),NULL, NULL),4326);
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SDO_UTIL` package has a function named `SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES` which returns the coordinates of the vertices of the input geometry.

If you modify your funtcion this way:

```
create or replace function transform_long_lat_pt(longitude in number, 
                                           latitude in number)
return VERTEX_SET_TYPE deterministic is
begin
     return SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES(sdo_cs.transform(sdo_geometry(2001, 3763, 
                sdo_point_type(longitude, latitude, NULL),NULL, NULL),4326));
end;
```

You can get the latitude and longitude just by doing `result.x` and `result.y`

See the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_util.htm#SPATL1237

Comment: Thanks, but there's a Function error on line 5:  • Error(5,6): PL/SQL: Statement ignored 
• Error(5,13): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Answer (score 0):

You could just sdo_cs.transform directly in the sql query instead of inside the function. Here's a simplified version of your query. This gets the centroid of a county (which is in Spherical Mercator) and the Lang/Lat (in 4326) for the same point and returns the X and Y for each.

```
select county, r.centroid.sdo_point.x, r.centroid.sdo_point.y, state, 
r.cent4326.sdo_point.x Longitude, r.cent4326.sdo_point.y Latitude from 
(select county, sdo_geom.sdo_centroid(geom, 0.05) centroid, state, 
sdo_cs.transform(sdo_geom.sdo_centroid(geom, 0.05), 4326) cent4326 
from counties_spmerc where rownum < 2) r ;
```

COUNTY                          CENTROID.SDO_POINT.X CENTROID.SDO_POINT.Y

---

STATE                           LONGITUDE   LATITUDE

---

Towns                                     -9321593.3           4152521.68 
Georgia                        -83.7372973 34.9163679

The above was done on a 12.1 instance and the sdo_centroid does not need the dim info.

Unless your area geometries contain circular arcs you don't need the arc_densify call.

so omitting sdo_arc_densify (and the dim info assuming it's an 11g or higher database) your query could be written as

```
SELECT IPID, v.centriod.sdo_point.x as M, 
v.centriod.sdo_point.y as P, CONCHELO, 
v.centriod_4326.sdo_point.x as Longitude, 
v.centriod_4326.sdo_point.y as Latitude FROM
(SELECT A.ipid, 
SDO_GEOM.SDO_CENTROID(A.GEOMETRY, 0.05) as centroid, 
A.CONCELHO, 
SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(SDO_GEOM.SDO_CENTROID(A.GEOMETRY, 0.05), 4326) 
as centriod_4326, 
FROM VAETA A) V
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jayant, much appreciated . Sorry for the late reply